# Keras - shapes mismatch using convolutional nets

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, keras, conv-neural-network

I built my keras model in the following way (this is of course not the final production ready model):

```py
self.model = Sequential()        
self.model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(674, 514, 1), padding='same', 
activation='relu'))
self.model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=
['accuracy'])
```

Model summary is:

```py
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 674, 514, 32)      320       
=================================================================
Total params: 320
Trainable params: 320
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

I try to fit it in the following way:

```py
self.model.fit(self.input_images, self.output_images, batch_size=32, 
epochs=10, verbose=1, shuffle=True)
```

Shapes of both training input and output (`self.input_images, self.output_images`) are both `(100, 674, 514, 1)`.

And when i try to train my model I get the following exception:

```py
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_1 to have shape 
(674, 514, 32) but got array with shape (674, 514, 1)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mismatch is with your `output_images`. The result of the convolutional layer is `(None, 674, 514, 32)`, because it has 32 filters. The loss `mean_squared_error` tells keras to expect a compatible label shape (which the supplied `output_images` is not).

The model isn't finished and normally CNN has many convolutional and downsampling layers, so the output shape is going to be different. But if you want you can make *this model* work by either changing the number of filters to 1...

```
Conv2D(1, ...)
```

... or by making `output_images` a tensor of shape `(100, 674, 514, 32)`.